# Jquery DIVs Not Sliding Correctly in Animation

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I'm working on this site and I would like when the user clicks on a navigation item a div slides out to the right and reveals the content for that section, and when the user clicks on the next navigation item the current div would slide back into the left and the next div would slide out to the right. I have this kind of working here: http://fire4hirecatering.com/workingsite/

However, if you notice after clicking through each of the navigation items once and then returning to a page it shows the content for that div before the animation happens.

I'm new to JQuery so I'm sure this is not polished but here it is:

```
function navAbout() {
if($('#main_content').hasClass("redLeft")) {
    //Current Div Content Slideout
    $('.selected').animate({
        width: '0px'
        }, 1200, 'swing').hide(1200);
    $('#aboutSlide').delay(1200).show().animate({
        width: '550px'
        }, 1200, 'swing' );
    $('#aboutContent').delay(2400).fadeIn(600);
        $("#aboutSlide").addClass("selected").not("#aboutSlide").removeClass("selected");

     /*Below three lines were the only way to get the class "selected" removed, the code above wasn't working*/
    $('#menuSlide').removeClass("selected");
    $('#mediaSlide').removeClass("selected");
    $('#contactSlide').removeClass("selected");
    $('html').css("background-image", "url(img/bg_about.jpg)")
}

else {
    //animate the redBG to the left when user clicks nav
    $('#main_contentBG').animate({
        left: '40px'
        }, 1200, 'swing' );
    $('#main_content').addClass('redLeft');
    //About Div Content Slideout
    $('#aboutSlide').delay(1200).show().animate({
        width: '550px'
        }, 1200, 'swing' );
    $('#aboutSlide').addClass('selected');
    $('#aboutContent').delay(2100).fadeIn(600);
    //change background image
    $('html').css("background-image", "url(img/bg_about.jpg)")
}
}
```

You can see the whole site source at the link above. The JQuery is in the scripts.js file.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when the divs slide back the content is still visible until it reaches the left and hide. In css you can add overflow hidden in each container div. I think you can also do this in js, by showing the content after the slide is finished.

```
#aboutSlide{
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
#menuSlide{
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
#mediaSlide{
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
#mediaSlide{
  ...
  overflow: hidden;
}
```